# NotFoundHttpException given when trying to access laravel route by posting to it from other page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I've got a cms sitting in the webroot of example.dev and i have a laravel app sitting in example.dev/book. Both work fine.

I want to post a form on a page at example.dev and send the user with it to example.com/book/login

I have a route setup in laravel so if you go to example.com/book/login it echoes some data at the moment which works fine.

My problem is that if from example.dev i submit that form to example.com/book/login i get a:

Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException

But if i just enter example.dev/book/login to my url, it doesn't error.

I have no idea why :(

Comment: ok, can you post your routes for login ? i suspect that you have setup the Route::get, but you forget to add the Route::post one which will work with the form (posting)

Comment: Yep, you are absolutely right. Just realised this myself!

Comment: i think you should close this too :D

Comment: I prefer to leave something for future idiots like myself :)

Comment: i dont know, its up to you

Answer (score 0):

Transpires the issue was that i forgot a Route::post in my routes file. All my routes were GET which is why a post didn't have a url to go to.

Hope this helps someone in the future!